# What are the pros and cons of letting colleagues know about very good grades?

Tags: colleagues, germany

I am currently employed as a working student in a German based company. We have mostly German employees but also quite a few international people working there. I think I have a good relationship with my colleagues. I like them and during friendly small talk they also ask me about my university.

I was away for a little over a month in order to have more time to study for the exams and I am gonna start working again during the semester break. I invested quite a lot of time and effort into studying and got a perfect grade on every exam.

When I start working again my colleagues will probably, maybe just out of courtesy, ask me how everything went and I don't know what the best answer would be and if I should mention my very good grades.

Usually I would just say something like: "Yeah, it went pretty well. I am happy with the results." because I don't want to come across as bragging and I would be afraid to be labeled in a negative way (young know-it-all). This is because several times during my work there I was in the situation where I had technical questions that no one in the team was able to answer, which I suspect was a uncomfortable situation for them. I am afraid that talking about the grades will somehow worsen the situation.

But at the same time I think that they probably don't even care because grades have no relation to achievements in the workplace and thus they would have no reason to feel threatened or become jealous. And on the contrary they might perceive me as someone who is a promising candidate for future employment.

Comment: Don't over think it. 1, no body really cares about your grade. 2, you are assuming your grades are better than your co-workers and it may create hard feeling. But you don't know that, your co-workers may have even better grades, they just don't talk about it.

Comment: Your exaggerated representation of my question leads me to believe that you suffer from a confirmation bias and thus you maybe have a personal problem with this subject. Where do you even get the idea that I wanted praise for myself? I think your comment (and my reply) are off-topic and should be deleted.

Comment: Almost nobody really cares about grades. They may care about what you learned and how well you learned it, which is a very different matter. Go apply your new knowledge.

Comment: "...what you learned and how well you learned it, which is a very different matter..." thats an interesting point of view, thank you.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: I can see how you might have misunderstood me: I meant not "to brag" but "to come across as bragging". Also jealousy does not necessarily mean that I see myself above them. Maybe jealousy was not the best word. What I mean is that I might be labeled as the young know-it-all who things he is above others.....Actually this is exactly what happened with you, so my fear was justified.

Comment: @problemofficer comments withdrawn

Comment: How you come across will probably come down to how you present it. For example, "I studied extensively, and in the end it paid off." vs. "I aced all the exams because I'm awesome.". If you emphasize the hard work you put into it, no one will assume you're bragging, even if you add that you had perfect results in the end.

Answer (score 11):

> When I start working again my colleagues will probably, maybe just out
>   of courtesy, ask me how everything went and I don't know what the best
>   answer would be and if I should mention my very good grades.

Unless you are trying to flaunt your exam results for some reason, a perfectly reasonable response is "It went well - thanks for asking" and leave it at that. If you want to brag a bit you might say "The time off for the extra work really paid off." Don't go further than that.

There's no need to say "I was absolutely perfect in every way", particularly if you already suspect it might cause bad feelings.

I have never known nor cared about the grades of co-workers. In my >40 years of working, I don't know anyone who has known or cared. You may be the only one if you do. How often have you discussed the grades of your coworkers during your friendly small talk? Perhaps that's common at your particular company, but I've never encountered it.

> But at the same time I think that they probably don't even care
>   because grades have no relation to achievements in the workplace and
>   thus they would have no reason to feel threatened or become jealous.

They probably don't care at all.

Unless you feel the need to be the only one who cares about grades in the workplace, just keep it to yourself and feel good about your accomplishment without trying to brag. You have a right to be proud. But trying to share that particular pride with others may very well come across as bragging.

> What are the pros and cons of letting colleagues know about very good
>   grades?

I see no real pros other than stroking your ego a bit. If you are applying to a new job at a company where a top GPA is a requirement, then grades are important. Even then, there is nothing to be gained by talking about your grades with co-workers. Job applications and interviews are the correct venue for discussing your perfect exam grades. Otherwise, nobody really cares.

The negatives are your relationships with your colleagues.

Comment: Imho your suggestion is almost identical to what I already wrote I was saying. The question is whether I am too humble.

Comment: "I was absolutely perfect in every way".  That is not what the OP wrote. There is no purpose the characterize what the OP wrote in that way.

Comment: I changed the title to be hopefully more descriptive. What I am missing in your answer are explanations. You only restate what I already suspected and also add your personal opinion that you never cared for grades.

Comment: +1 for "They probably don't care at all." This is pride wanting to manifest. Not only do other people not care, but pride presents itself as the stink of death. Everyone knows it when they see it right away, and it's going to hurt you because nobody likes it, though we all can/have suffered from it.

Comment: Remember, there is always someone out there smarter than you.

Comment: Note that the OP is German. In Germany, it is still customary (often required) to submit a transcript of your grades all the way to secondary school with each job application.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't think it would be customary to discuss grades with your colleagues but I am not completely sure. I am just saying it's a very different context than what you and I are used to elsewhere. People there do care in ways that I personally found very surprising.

Answer (score 3):

> I was away for a few months in order to have more time to study for
>   the exams and I am gonna start working again during the semester
>   break. I invested quite a lot of time and effort into studying and got
>   a perfect grade on every exam.
>
> When I start working again my colleagues will probably, maybe just out
>   of courtesy, ask me how everything went and I don't know what the best
>   answer would be and if I should mention my very good grades.

People who don't care about you, or if they don't like you, won't be making small talk like that with you. If they ask, they remembered why you were away, and what you were doing. They do care!

Your company gave you a few months away to study for your exams. I am sure the company was affected in at least some ways. Some of the work that would have been yours was probably sent your colleagues' way.

You don't have to mention that you got 100% in all the exams but you can rephrase that in a professional way and thank your colleagues.

*I did very well in my exams actually, I was able to completely focus on studying and got A+ in all of my courses! Really lucky that I was given time off, otherwise that wouldn't have been possible.*

If your university/college has some sort of an award for students with high grades, you can mention that award in place of the grade.

> They might perceive me as someone who is a promising candidate for
>   future employment.

Perfect reason to actually mention doing really well!

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking good grades will get you in the door. Most employers do not really care so long as you graduated with said degree.

With that said you can mention grades but imagine if your co-worker got the job while you're stuck with just good grades? As a worker myself I known people with straight As in school who cannot do much of anything else at work. I believe you should concentrate on doing well at work, understanding the material, and making a good impression with your bosses. You'll be far more likely offered a job than just coming there saying you got perfect grades.